# Ansible use variable into other variable

Tags: variables, ansible

I'm configuring Ansible role to install a specific Nginx version.
This is the folder structure:

```
nginx
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── molecule
│   └── default
│       ├── collections.yml
│       ├── converge.yml
│       ├── molecule.yml

│       └── verify.yml
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
└── templates
    ├── nginx.j2
    └── nginx.repo
```

Now I have two problems:

1. How can define `nginx_package` variable using `version` variable?

```
---
defaults:
 user: nginx
 group: nginx
 version: 1.19.2
 #nginx_package: nginx-1.19.2-1.el7.ngx
 nginx_package: nginx-{{defaults.version}}-1.el7.ngx
 OS: centos
 OSRELEASE: 7
```

2. Can I (and how can) use a variable `version` into the file `molecule\default\verify.yml`

Thanks for the support.

Comment: For the first question, you can directly use version variable while declaring nginx_package variable as follows: ```nginx_package: nginx-{{version}}-1.el7.ngx```

Comment: Having a top-level `defaults:` dict will make it difficult to work with individual key-pairs inside it. Better to keep each role default variable separate, i.e. `nginx_user: nginx`, `nginx_group: nginx`, etc,

Comment: Hi Unsel, thanks for the reply. I tried to use ```nginx_package: nginx-{{version}}-1.el7.ngx``` but I receive this error: ```FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {'version': '1.19.2', 'nginx_package': 'nginx-\"{{ version }}\"-1.el7.ngx',
'version' is undefined```

Comment: Hi Seshadri_c, thanks for your comment. I can't change the ```defaults``` structure.

Comment: Then you'll have to define other variable outside the `defaults` dict. Values within the dict structure can not be cross-referenced. `nginx_package: nginx-{{defaults.version}}-1.el7.ngx` will work when you put it outside `defaults:`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use set_fact in main/task.yaml to set a variable using another variable.
   Doc: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html